# Is there a way to group nth-child CSS rules for same parent

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following CSS rules:

```css
 #div .item62 > .wrap > .cont > .level1 > div:nth-child(9),
 #div .item62 > .wrap > .cont > .level1 > div:nth-child(11),
 #div .item62 > .wrap > .cont > .level1 > div:nth-child(n+12){
    width: 140px ;
 }
```

I would like to group those rules to make the code shorter and probably to make the code more efficient when the parent element selection would be done once(do those rules make the browser engine search three times the same "parent" element or is this already optimized?).

Is there a way to write these rules in a shorter way?

As the code structure is created by third party code I cannot add a distinct class or change HTML structure.

I could not find a CSS method that would allow to select one parent with multiple distinct child elements without rewriting the whole path to the child elements.
Also I have no additional CSS preprocessors avaliable.

Answer (score 2):

Your current CSS rule is the shortest you can write without any *Preprocessor* available.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, but I hoped that maybe there is some new syntax or construction avaliable, so let's see if there will be some suggestions.

Comment: Other than the nth-child part. It is also dependent on your HTML. If there are no divs in between. I would erase from .wrap to .level1,

Comment: That's another "direction", I am just curious if the nth-child part can be grouped in some way.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `:nth-child(n+12)` matches every child starting with and including `:nth-child(12)`. Assuming the `11` and `n+12` are not typos, you can condense them to a single `n+11` expression:

```css
#div .item62 > .wrap > .cont > .level1 > div:nth-child(9),
#div .item62 > .wrap > .cont > .level1 > div:nth-child(n+11)
```

Notice now that `:nth-child(9), :nth-child(n+11)` is essentially the same as `:nth-child(n+9)`, i.e. everything starting with and including `:nth-child(9)`, *but* excluding `:nth-child(10)`.

With this in mind, you can rewrite the above selector list using `:not(:nth-child(10))`:

```css
#div .item62 > .wrap > .cont > .level1 > div:nth-child(n+9):not(:nth-child(10))
```

Now you have a single complex selector with a negation. I cannot comment on the performance implications of having a negation in the mix, however unless profiling shows that this selector causes significant performance issues, I'd say that for reducing your selector list by more than half the bytes, it's absolutely worth it. Personally, I can't imagine `:not(:nth-child(10))` being much cheaper or much more expensive than `:nth-child(n+b)` for any nonzero `b`. Each of these is a pretty complex operation by itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this particular case I really needed the 9th and all elements after and including 11th element. This additional :not statement makes the condensed rule possible here. However, I was looking for a general grouping rule that would also apply to arbitrary subsets of child elements, which are not simply selectable by (an+b). But +1 for the combination of :nth-child and :not.

Comment: @AndyZ: That is true - combining arbitrary selectors is not possible, until browsers implement the new `:matches()` pseudo-class from Selectors 4, which will allow you to write something like `div:matches(:nth-child(9), :nth-child(11))`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, it won't be much shorter and is technically redundant.

```
#div > .item62 > .wrap > .cont > .level1 > div:nth-child(2n+9),
#div > .item62 > .wrap > .cont > .level1 > div:nth-child(n+12)
{
  width:140px;
}
```

Comment: That's less selective, and will match any `div` inside `#div`, not requiring the intermediate class element selectors.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I have to use the exact selection chain, because it's a multi row, multi column, custom sized element menu and I just need to give a few divs a specific width, but the divs have no id's and no unique classes, so I can reference them only by this chained css selector.