# Specifying a list of arbitrary children (no pattern) for nth-child and nth-of-type

Tags: css, css-selectors

So I've now read enough about various funky `nth-child` and `nth-of-type` patterns to have the seventh son of the seventh son fly a space-ship backwards to Pluto and back. But I still haven't come across a way to simply provide a list of specific children in a concise way. It'd work like so:

```
td:nth-child(1,3,7,10) { text-align: center; ... }
```

The above syntax would obviously be mighty convenient for example when styling table cells. That something like this would exist, seems like a no-brainer to me. Of course I can always use:

```
td:nth-child(1), td:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(7), td:nth-child(10) { ... }
```

But that's just so much redundant repetition and clutter in my CSS. Particularly when I need to also have a class name specified before the td. Then it becomes as bloated as this, for example:

```
.study_references td:nth-child(1), .study_references td:nth-child(3), .study_references td:nth-child(7), .study_references td:nth-child(10) { ... }
```

I'd really like to have my CSS look a bit more elegant, concise, and readable. Is there really no way to provide a specific list of nth-s to the selector in one shot? (Not looking for a preprocessor fix.)

Comment: I am afraid you can't since there is no pattern.

Comment: This would be a great addition to the CSS standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't. Neither [Selectors 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4) nor [CSS Syntax 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-syntax/#anb) have extended the An+B notation to allow a *list* of such expressions as in your `1,3,7,10` example either, though I wonder if it may be worth suggesting as it seems pretty doable. In fact, I just went ahead and [suggested this](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Jun/0260.html) (I couldn't find any earlier proposals using either the mailing list search, or Google).

The closest to a solution that Selectors 4 offers is via the `:matches()` pseudo, which makes it so that the only bit you have to repeat is `:nth-child(...)`:

```
.study_references td:matches(
  :nth-child(1), :nth-child(3), :nth-child(7), :nth-child(10)
) { ... }
```

But this is still far from ideal, and is not yet implemented anyway.

If you can suss out at least *part* of a pattern from most of the numeric indices you're looking for, you could modify this pattern as necessary using `:not()` and/or additional `:nth-child()`/`:nth-last-child()` and still pick up the right elements. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309606/is-there-a-way-to-group-nth-child-css-rules-for-same-parent/30322912#30322912) where I refactor [9, 11, n+12] into [n+9 except 10]. However this is likely more trouble than it's worth, and the resulting selector will almost always be far from elegant unless you get really lucky as I did above.

Comment: Why is it unfortunate, and why is it a good idea? You say it could be "very handy". All you are doing is saving a few bytes of code, at the cost of complexifying the spec and supporting an incoherent CSS model where people target specific elements by their position in the HTML.

Comment: @torazaburo: Same reason why :not() was extended and :matches() was added - it's not just about the bytes, it's about the succinctness. What do you mean by an "incoherent CSS model" though?

Comment: @torazaburo Saving a few bits of code is not as important as readability and ease of editing. I'm sure you can see that tweaking a simple list in one place would be more convenient than reviewing each parentheses. (Though I do want to save the redundantly repeated bits that would go into declaring a class for each `td` and tripling the markup character bits per each table cell, as far as that solution goes.)

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for popping in the suggestion to the list, and for the heads-up on `matches` whenever it becomes more widely supported. I'm all for factoring even partial patterns in all sorts of things including the clouds in the sky and the food on my plate, but I have a gut feeling I might spend a lot of time re-factoring my stylesheets' nth-algorithms when I want to modify column sequences in the HTML...

Comment: @BoltClock With all due respect, comparisons to `:not`, at least, are not appropriate, because `:not` allows you to do things otherwise impossible. I agree that `:matches()` is syntactic sugar, but the situation is a bit different there as well, because it helps avoid a combinatorial explosion of rules. Here, we are just talking about bits of syntactic sugar. Sure, syntactic sugar is great, but as a wise man once said, too much syntactic sugar will give you cancer of the semi-colon. The standards committees have more important things to do. Man up and write out your rules.

Comment: @torazaburo: Agreed on :not(). Whether the feature is worth considering is something that I'd much rather hear straight from the horse's mouth - even if it's not worth it I'm sure the WG will be more than happy to let us know.

Answer (score 0):

When CSS lacks a feature, Sass can help. You can try a formula like this one in Sass. It's not the most elegant solution, but perhaps you can improve on it.

```
$children: 1,3,7,10;

@each $child in $children {
  td:nth-child(#{$child}) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Guess you missed the "(Not looking for a preprocessor fix.)" part of the question.

Comment: I may get tired of fiddling with the repetitions and do a bit of preprocessing if I run into many more of these cases. Already doing it in some cases (albeit with a lite home-brew preprocessor), after facing the need and discovering that CSS variables and calc were still quite poorly supported.

Comment: I indeed missed the preprocessor part of the question, sorry. 

I created a habit to resort to those when I see a limitation with CSS.